# Displaying complete rows of grouped query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with names and medical prescriptions. What I what to do is loop through all prescriptions belonging to a specific name and show them in a table, and then create a new table with the next name and a new set of prescriptions.

When I use GROUP BY, I am able to display the name of a patient and the first table row of each group. But I do not know how to populate rows from the sub_fields within the groups. I have tried with `GROUP_CONCAT`, and it allows me to show all rows of a column from the group as comma-separated, but still I need to populate all the data from the sub rows like this:

NAME1:
 - START1_1
 - END1_1
 - DRUGID1_1

- START1_2
- END1_2
- DRUGID1_2
- START1_3
- END1_3
- DRUGID1_3

NAME2:
 - START2_1
 - END2_1
 - DRUGID2_1

- START2_2
- END2_2
- DRUGID2_2
- START2_3
- END2_3
- DRUGID2_3

I have tried with the following code, using Group by, and I have also tried using GROUP_CONCAT, but I do not know how to handle the output.

```
$med = "SELECT  *  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}medicin_skema GROUP BY elevnavn";

 foreach ($wpdb->get_results($med, ARRAY_A ) as $row) {
     echo '<br>'.$row['elevnavn'].' ';
     echo '<br>'.$row['start_dato'].' ';
     echo '<br>'.$row['slut_dato'].' ';
     echo '<br><br>'.$row['drugid'].' '; 
 }
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If I understand correctly - you are grouping by the patient's name - so you will get one record PER PATIENT NAME.

The brute force approach is to select a distinct array of patient names; then select each of their prescriptions ordered by start date or / end date or whatever sensible option you want - then do your creation?

A sub-select in essence (I assume elevnavn is NAME)

```
SELECT distinct(elevnavn) from {$wpdb->prefix}medicin_skema

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$name=$row[0];
$newquery="SELECT * from {$wpdb->prefix}medicin_skema where elevnavn='".$name"'";
execute the query
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
   {
        retrieve dates, drug id etc
        new create query
   }

 }
```

You can also do a insert (select from) but you will need to get the sub-select correct first and use a left join to get ALL the records for each name.

Comment: SORRY - I misunderstood - you are trying to collect an array result for the grouped query - you need to WHILE or FOREACH through the SUBARRAY ARRAY_A

Comment: Distinct is not a function, and surely we can't be advocating an insecure, and long since deprecated API in this day and age.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM medicin_skema 
 GROUP 
    BY elevid
```

This query returns a nonsensical (or 'indeterminate') result. In the absence of any aggregating functions, it's meaningless to include a GROUP BY clause. Also, never use evil `SELECT *` - it just adds to the confusion.

You then use this query in a loop to generate n further queries. This is ludicrous! Instead just create one query with a join, if necessary.

Finally, you're directly including variables in your query string. This is considered insecure and bad practice. Instead, always use prepared and bound queries.

If you would like further help with constructing a sensible and secure query, consider revising your question as per the following advice. Note that there are 3 parts to it. [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this actually makes a lot of sense, although I am not a good enough programmer, to actually put your advice to practice. Before I do write a revised question, I will have to do a litte reading up on some of the concepts you used. Again, thanks.

Comment: You are a good enough programmer to put the above into practice. As a lousy programmer, I can absolutely guarantee this to be true

Answer (score -1):

It worked very well what you did. I ended up with this, which works:

```
$med = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}medicin_skema GROUP BY elevid";
                $drugname = '';
                $dato = '';

foreach( $wpdb->get_results($med, ARRAY_A) as $medicinskema ) 
{
$name=$medicinskema['elevid'];
                echo '<table class="cpt-table"><tbody>';
                    echo '<tr><th colspan="3">Elev: ' . $medicinskema['elevid'] . '</th>';
                    echo '<th colspan="6">CPRnr.: ' . $medicinskema['elevcpr'] . '</th>';
                    echo '<th colspan="5">Udfyldt: ' . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($medicinskema['time'])) . '</th></tr>';$newquery = "SELECT * from {$wpdb->prefix}medicin_skema where elevid='$name'";
$prescriptions = $wpdb->get_results($newquery, ARRAY_A);
    // dumping($prescriptions);
    foreach($prescriptions as $prescription) 
   {
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that. I get that you think this is a bit backway, but I do not know how to handle it properly.